# Image and graphics Java

Tags: java, image, graphics

hy,
I've a little probleme with a graphics. I've an image witch I resize like this :

```
Image BigImage = img.getScaledInstance(115, 154, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
```

and I tried ti draw it on a graphic:

```
g2.drawImage(BigImage, 0, 0, null);
```

it's unfortunately not working.
it only work if i add ***ImageIcon te = new ImageIcon(BigImage);***

```
Image BigImage = img.getScaledInstance(115, 154, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
ImageIcon te = new ImageIcon(BigImage);
g2.drawImage(BigImage, 0, 0, null);
```

Do you have any idea why? Have you another way to do it?

Comment: "it's unfortunately not working" -> do you get an `Exception` of some sort? Or is the image not scaled? What exactly is the problem that you encounter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't say right now why your code doesn't work, but you can directly draw a scaled instance of the image using [this drawImage method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawImage%28java.awt.Image,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20java.awt.image.ImageObserver%29). It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

The documenttion for [Image.getScaledInstance()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html#getScaledInstance%28int,%20int,%20int%29) states in part..

> The new Image object may be loaded **asynchronously** even if the original source image has already been loaded completely.

(My emphasis)

One way to correct the problem is to add the image to a MediaTracker to ensure it is loaded before rendering.  But most importantly, do not do any of this from within the paint()/paintComponent() method, which is what I suspect given the code snippet.  The instantiation of the ImageIcon was probably slowing down the execution just enough for the image to load.

Another tip I will offer is that you will get better help sooner if you post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).  This is particularly useful for image based examples, since if you'd hot-linked to an image available on the net, we could've seen just how big the image was that was being rescaled.  ;)